# How to monitor app user Acquisitions from firebase dynamic links

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics, firebase-dynamic-links

On Google analytics dashboard, we can monitor several acquisition channels. We recently leveraged the power of firebase dynamic links in our user acquisition efforts. We want to know the impact this had. The problem is that, Google analytics shows us a spike in acquisitions via **Push Notifications** at the same moment when we released the dynamic links to the public.

[image]

We suspect that this spike in push notifications acquisitions represents dynamic links user acquisitions, since we've not made any major changes push notifications we send to our users but we're not sure. Can someone please tell us if we're right or if there's a way to measure acquisitions via dynamic links.